# Excel:Add items to dropdown

Tags: excel, vba

I have a list of data in sheet1 in column A, I used these values as items in dropdown in column B same sheet. I have added the dropdown from datavalidation. Now if I add more values in column A the value added should be displayed in dropdown added.

Is there a way to achieve this?

I tried checking properties of the dropdown,I couldn`t see any name for the dropdown to add more items.

I think we got to write macro for this.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a name to the range in column a (highlight column a, choose the formulas menu and then define name) call it colA - then when you set up the drop down (data menu, data validation, LIST type put:

=colA

as the source.

Now whatever values are added to column A they will update the drop down list.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I didnt get your answer.please be more clear.

Comment: Ohh I got it. It works. but drop down displays with blank value. Is there a way to avoid it?

Comment: You can get rid of the blanks by using dynamic range names (search and you will find) or using Excel's built-in tables as your source: http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2013/09/10/naming-table-columns/